# Is it possible to manage a GIT non-bare repo from Google Drive?

Tags: git, github, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm a Javascript developer and I'm working on a online JS editor with Google Drive integration showing your Drive files in a side bar. As many JS developers uses Github as repository I would love to allow commits, pull and push from the sidebar.

The problem is those files are stored on Google Drive so I should have to execute the "git commit", "git pull", etc... in the Drive folder. Does anybody knows if it's possible?

I've googled a lot but everything I found is about use Drive as storage for a git bare repository. I want to keep Github as central repo, I just want to have a clone in my Drive account.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it safe to keep your repository on a google drive directory? Surely you could end up with inconsistent repository while it syncs, and have it get very confused? (I don't know this is just a question)

Comment: Well possibly, if you sync Drive on your local machine. For me I do not, I work directly on Google Drive, I only need a good online code editor to get rid of my local disc.

Comment: (and a way to edit, commit and push from the cloud)

Comment: perhaps a pure JS implementation of git would be of help? something along the lines of https://github.com/danlucraft/git.js ? not sure if it supports everything you need

Comment: The problem is not the language, the problem is I have no local drive to execute git commands. I can't found a way to ask this GIT implementation to load files using the Google Drive API

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now that I understand the question...

I think you need a file system driver that talks to the Google Drive API. That would let Git talk to the Google Drive API like it talks to every other filesystem without having to load all of the Google Drive files, code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Drive folder is just a folder that replicates across multiple machines (using the Google Drive 'magic' infrastructure code), so as long as your PC & network can keep up with the changes there should be no problems with a cloned repo in a Google Drive directory.

Having said that, I've had Google Drive take several minutes to sync when my Git history ran deep while making a plain backup copy of the repo to the Google Drive (20k LOC with lots of commits).

Comment: Actualy, I'm not replicating my Google Drive folder, I'm accessing my files throght the Google Drive API. So as I'm not mounting anything locally I don't know how to execute GIT commands.

Comment: I think you need a file system driver that talks to the Google Drive API. That would let Git talk to the Google Drive API like it talks to every other filesystem without having to load all of the Google Drive files, code, etc.

Comment: Oh! you mean like a fuse module? This could work. Can you post the comment as answer to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [GDriveFS](https://github.com/dsoprea/GDriveFS/), a FUSE wrapper for Google Drive in Python.